# How do I center the Zurb Foundation top bar nav?

Tags: css, navigation, center, zurb-foundation, nav

The top bar nav on [my site](http://www.endsnore.com/_test1/marketing1.html) is left aligned like this:

```
| Home | aveoTSD | Silent Nite          |
```

I would like to center the top bar nav like this:

```
|          Home | aveoTSD | Silent Nite          |
```

Center it exactly like the red bar with "Example" text.

Here is [my css](http://www.endsnore.com/_test1/css/foundation.css).

Comment: I recommend you toss everything into a JSFiddle and post a link to the JSFiddle, or post all your relevant HTML and CSS directly here rather than link it.

Comment: I prefer to work with the live site, so the link at the top was fine.

Comment: @user2343800 consider my answer over the one you have accepted

Comment: what about adding .row to the nav? as it is automatically centering things, this could work as a trick.

Comment: <div class="top-bar" id="example-menu">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="top-bar-left">
               ..............

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do it by adding this to your CSS (and preferably removing conflicting styles):

```
.top-bar-section ul {display: table; margin: 0 auto;}
.top-bar-section ul li {display: table-cell;}
```

Comment: +1 -- this works perfectly and is generally the standard for doing full width centered list items. Not sure why it was voted down.

Comment: when I did this it messed up the small mobile version, especially for anything items with drop downs. anyone else have this problem or know the solution?

Comment: You probably should post a new question with a link for help on this.

Comment: @ralph.m I went ahead and did that and got shafted by moderators for duplicate questions... anyone looking to implement this without affecting effecting functionality see my answer here

Answer (score 5):

Found this to be helpful:
https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/1598

Set the container of the navigation to:
**text-align:center;**

Then for the navigation itself, set the display to:
**display:inline-block;**

Hope that helps!

Comment: to see the code behind implementing this solution see the answer below

Answer (score 2):

Here is the best solution I've found that works for all resize events. It centers the Foundation 5 Top-bar elements.

SCSS:

```
nav.top-bar:not(.expanded) {
            text-align: center;
            section.top-bar-section { display: inline-block; }
                           }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="contain-to-grid">
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar>
    <ul class="title-area">
        <li class="name">
            <h1><a href="#"></a></h1>
        </li>
        <!-- Remove the class "menu-icon" to get rid of menu icon. Take out "Menu" to just have icon alone -->
        <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
    </ul>

    <section class="top-bar-section">
        <ul>
            <li><%= link_to 'LINK 1', root_path %></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><%= link_to 'LINK2', link_path %></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="has-dropdown">
                <%= link_to 'Droping', "#" %>
                <ul class="dropdown">
                    <li><label>Label:</label></li>
                    <li><%= link_to 'DROP 1', drop_path %></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><%= link_to 'DROP 2', drop_path %></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
        </ul>
    </section>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the above example, I make a few tweaks.  The above centers everything.  The adjustments below centers the topbar, left justifies the text on drop-downs and centers the "hamburger" / menu-icon when in mobile:

```
/* center topbar */
/* set alignment to center for small screens */
nav.top-bar { text-align:center; }
nav.top-bar:not(.expanded) {
        text-align: center;
        section.top-bar-section { 
            /* align drop down menu text to left on large screens */
            text-align:left; 
            display: inline-block;

         }


}
/* center the mobile hamburger menu */
.top-bar .toggle-topbar.menu-icon {
 padding: 0;
 right: 50%;
 margin-right: -36px;
}
```