# Center elements on Zurb Foundation Top-Bar

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

I have a top nav-bar made with Foundation 5.

The elements on the nav-bar should be centered. I realize that this question has been asked before(for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16866734/how-do-i-center-the-zurb-foundation-top-bar-nav)), but none of the answers provided so far have worked. You can see the problem also elsewhere.

As a perfect example of non-centered elements on a nav-bar, check the "Base 2013" template on [this website](https://www.templatemonster.com/blog/free-zurb-foundation-templates/). Download it and open the index.html and you'll see the problem right there.

Various methods have not worked for me so far. Some of the failed experiments:

Set `margin: 0px auto;` to the `<ul>` or other elements.

Same applies to `text-align:center;`.

Any ideas on how to center the elements on this nav-bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `flex` for that with `justify-content` like this

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.parent div {
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

I added padding just to make elements wider and to not stick to each other.

Read more about flex [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Excellent. That is it. Thank you. I tried flex before, but only used "align-items: center". That obviously didn't work.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

If someone else runs into the same issue, note that the above answer is correct, yet breaks the responsiveness of the menu. To fix that, add the following CSS to the above:

```
@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
  .parent {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

This will allow the menu items to flow as intended again.

The padding shouldn't be necessary when using the Foundation classes.

'Thank you' to [Mileta Dulovic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10765428/mileta-dulovic) for providing the correct path to the solution.